# Can't run React Native project on real Android device

Tags: android, react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I am beginner in React Native. I used to run my project on real Android device, by running the Metro Bundler, and then through LAN option, scan the QR code with Expo application on my Android phone. And it worked fine.
[Metro Bundler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc1zG.png)

Now when I try the same, blue screen with "Something went wrong" appears, and the error log

> Uncaught Error:java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to / {the ip address}

I tried to run the project through USB cable & tried to reinstall Expo application on Android & tried to run another project on another computer by Expo application & tried to run old project used to run normally, and the same error is still appear.

Tried to use tunnel option in the Metro Bundler, new error appears

> Uncaught Error: java.lang.Exception
> [Error when connect through tunnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj3Rv.png)

Note that the application is working fine on the web browser.

How to solve this problem and run the application on my Android device?

Comment: try to open the tunnel url in your web browser, what do you see?

also, if you plug in your device over usb you can change the connection type to localhost and then press the button to start it on android. this will run `adb reverse` for you and you should be able to run the app just fine as long as the device is connected

Comment: @brentvatne I connected my device through USB, and pressed (Run on Android device/emulater), Expo application on my Android is opened, and after a while of loading it shows (Network response timed out). With error log (Uncaught Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting all of my code, I found that there is a mistake while importing another JavaScript file in my code. I wrote the path name in small-case letters, while the real path is capital letter.
It's weird it didn't raise any error or warning while running the project on the web browser. Morover, the Android Expo application did't provide informative log error.